# Unable to publish using Clickonce [disconnected from network error]

Tags: clickonce

The error details are:

```
    Error   1   Failed to connect to 'ftp://www.xyz.com/xyz_Publish/' with the
following error: Unable to create the Web 'ftp://www.xyz.com/xyz_Publish/'.  The computer is disconnected from the network
            1   1   xyz.PresentationLayer
```

It doesent matter what credentials(correct or incorrect), its is giving the same error everytime. I can connect to the ftp using filezilla and via firefox/IE.

Since yesterday everything was working fine and this error just creeped up from nowhere.

Edit: Unable to deploy any application. Getting the same error.

Comment: Check proxy server settings or your hosts file.

Comment: Where can I find the hosts file or proxy server settings?

Comment: I checked the hosts file, its empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2005 had to be reinstalled to fix the problem.